# Alpakka S3Client throws OptionVal$.contains NoSuchMethodError

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, akka, alpakka

I am trying to use the [Alpakka S3 connector](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/s3.html)

When I instantiate the S3Client I get the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: akka.util.OptionVal$.contains$extension(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)
```

It occurs at

```
  override def offsetOfModule(out: OutPort): Int = {
if (outPort.contains(out)) {
  pendingBuilder match {
    case OptionVal.Some(composite) ⇒ composite.offsetOfModule(out)
    case OptionVal.None            ⇒ 0 // Output belongs to the last module, which will be materialized *first*
  }
} else
  throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Port $out cannot be accessed in this builder")
```

}

in akka-stream (2.11 vs 2.5.12). The variable outPort is of type OptionVal.

The method does indeed not exist in OptionVal of the util package in akka-actor_2.11:2.2.20. Same in the [akka actor repository](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/util/OptionVal.scala). But [here](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/util/OptionVal$.html) it is documented as existing.

Why do these methods not exist? Do I miss a dependency? I used

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.lightbend.akka</groupId>
    <artifactId>akka-stream-alpakka-s3_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>0.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Or you can have a look at https://github.com/zengularity/benji

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that some dependency pulled in `akka-actor_2.11` version `2.2.20` which is very old and does not have the method mentioned in the exception.

Take a look at the output of `mvn dependency:analyze` and `mvn dependency:tree` and see which dependency brings in outdated Akka. Then update that dependency or force the usage of the latest Akka in your project by adding

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-actor_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.13</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

to your POM.